# show the 6th item in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript

I've got a script that allows me to search my Google Sheets doc and returns a row of items in an array. I've console.logged the results see image but I can't workout how I only (alert) the 6th item?

[image]

I know this is basic stuff but I can't work it out on my own.

Here's my code

```
function showPrice(el, arrayOfArrays, index) {
    const results = arrayOfArrays.filter(r => r[0] === "Dog");
    alert(results[6]);
  }
```

I get undefined?

Comment: Please update your code to a [mcve] using `[<>]` snippet editor. And then console.log(results.length)

Comment: Given results is an "array of arrays", you are currently trying to select the 7th array (because it starts at 0) not the 7th value in the first array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter returns the outer array since its first array's 0th entry is Dog

The outer array's length is 1

So perhaps you want to show the 6th entry of the nested array returns in the filter?

```js
const arr = [
  ["Dog", "Colorbyte", 40, 700, 1, 2, 3, 4]
]

function showPrice(el, arrayOfArrays, index) {
  const results = arrayOfArrays.filter(r => r[0] === "Dog");
  console.log(results.length)
  console.log(results[0][6]);
}

showPrice(null,arr,null)
```